# AJAX GET requests with Varnish Cache

Tags: ajax, wordpress, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have got an AJAX request running on a server with varnish. The request is as follows:

```
    (function() {
        $("#name").autocomplete({
            minLength:3, //minimum length of characters for type ahead to begin
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: php_vars.var_1, //your server side script
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        postcode: request.term
                    },

                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Success");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
})();
```

For the url, I use wp_localize_scripts and array with the absolute URL of the php script. I have consoled this url before this script and it is ok.

I have this setup on a server not running with varnish and it works fine. However on my server with varnish, I have noticed that the request URL is not correct (should be "auspost.php" and instead it is the page url with the query params). On my none varnish server the GET request url is correct.

It looks like varnish is caching my GET requests. Any advice would be very much appreciated! I can pastebin my vcl config if need be?

Comment: how about `cache:false`

Comment: Good idea but no luck. I can see from inspector that request url is still incorrect. I can see the headers are also sent via varnish:

Answer (score 1):

For ajax requests you should have the following header available
X-Reqeusted-With: XMLHttpRequest

In your varnish vcl_recv you can check if this header is present and force a pass.

```
if (req.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest"){
return (pass);
}
```