# Laravel : using Varnish and CSRF Token

Tags: php, laravel, csrf, varnish

I'm using Varnish to cache Laravel pages.

In order to display different CSRF Tokens for everyone, I use ESI to exclude CSRF from cache :

**app.blade.php**

```
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <title>@yield('title')</title>
        <meta name="description" content="@yield('description')">

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, initial-scale=1">
        <esi:include src="/esi" />
...
```

In /esi, I just use a controller to display the meta tag with the CSRF token

**csrf-token.blade.php**

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

In an ajax form, I get the token and pass it to a POST request :

**form.js**

```
this.formData._token = document.head.querySelector("[name~=csrf-token][content]").content;
axios.post('url', this.formData);
```

The _token sent via POST is received but when laravel tries to verify it, the one generated via the ESI is different from the one in $session->token().

Does anyone knows how to handle properly csrf with Varnish in Laravel ?

Here is my Varnish configuration file if it helps
**default.vcl**

```
sub vcl_recv {
    call devicedetect;

    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    if (req.esi_level == 0 && req.url ~ "^/esi(.*)?") {
        return (synth(403, "Error"));
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.url);

    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    if (req.http.X-UA-Device) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-UA-Device);
    }

    return (lookup);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (bereq.method != "GET"&&bereq.method != "HEAD") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Reverse-Proxy-TTL) {
        set beresp.ttl = std.duration(beresp.http.X-Reverse-Proxy-TTL + "s", 0s);
        unset beresp.http.X-Reverse-Proxy-TTL;
        return (deliver);
    }

    set beresp.do_esi = true;
    set beresp.grace = 5m;
    set beresp.ttl = 5h;
    set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "public, s-maxage=18000, maxage=3600";
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33670412/8607640 does this help?

Comment: Hello, actually no because i only handle GET requests with varnish, I pass the POST so the response is not cached (and the session token is updated at every call)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid your VCL file has some issues. Not just in regards to the CSRF token, but also in regards to conventional caching behavior. Some of the basic rules of the [built-in VCL][1] are disregarded in your configuration.

The Laravel documentation states that the CSRF token should match the value in the session data. However, your `vcl_backend_response` logic removes the `Set-Cookie` header almost unconditionally.

I believe we're going to need both the `Set-Cookie` response header and the `Cookie` request header to make sure the Laravel session remains active.

### Understand the business logic

Before we can write the proper VCL code, we need to make sure we understand the business logic behind CSRF tokens.

According to https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/0d601f598a2434b8b126c06af75a0f089b10a102/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php#L614-L617 the token is random string of 40 characters.

At first sight, the token seems to be unique per session and not per request. This means we can cache them as long as we have a cache variation per session.

### Passing the CSRF token during a POST call

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf states that CSRF tokens can be passed in 2 ways:

- Through a `_token` post field
- Through a `X-CSRF-TOKEN` request header

If you're planning to use a post field, this is what you're going to add:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

> It seems as though you're storing the token in a `<meta>` HTML tag, and passing it via Javascript logic as a `_token` input field. Not sure if that is the best way, but if you're sure that Laravel receives it as an `_token` field, all is good.

### Why are you experiencing a token mismatch?

I'm seeing a `unset beresp.http.set-cookie;` for responses received for every `POST` call. This means that a `Set-Cookie: laravel_session=xyz` will not be processed by the browser for `GET` calls.

But how can the token ever be set on your page, prior to passing it via a `POST` call, if the session is never established?

What will happen is that the `POST` request may contain a token, but because the `laravel_session` cookie is not sent to the backend, a new session will be established, and a new token will be generated.

### What are our options?

The easiest way forward is to accept a session being established when visiting the page that has the contact form.

#### Allow Laravel to generate the token

If 99% of your website doesn't rely on the `laravel_session` cookie, we can remove these cookies using VCL. We could for example only allow cookie processing on the `/esi` endpoint. I would be in favor of calling this the `/token` endpoint.

I would also cache the output from the `/token` endpoint, but I'd ensure that a cache variation is created per session.

And of course we need to clean up our VCL code to make this happen.

#### Generate the CSRF token ourselves

It is also possible to handle CSRF token generation in Varnish. This means the token is issued by Varnish and validated by Varnish.

It is also possible to integrate with Laravel and store the result in the Laravel session storage.

This option is a lot more complicated, but also more powerful.

I would suggest we try the first option and if it turns out that the ESI call doesn't yield the desired performance, we can still handle CSRF tokens in Varnish

### The VCL code

Here's the VCL code I would suggest. Keep in mind that I made some assumptions:

- The session cookie is named `laravel_session`
- The `devicedetect` subroutine is included from `/etc/varnish/devicedetect.vcl`
- The CSRF token endpoint is `/token`
- The `X-Reverse-Proxy-TTL` response header is used to set the TTL
- Session data is only needed on the `/token` endpoint

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;
include "devicedetect.vcl";

sub vcl_recv {
    call devicedetect;

    set req.http.Cookie = ";" + req.http.Cookie;
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "; +", ";");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";(laravel_session)=", "; \1=");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";[^ ][^;]*", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^[; ]+|[; ]+$", "");
    
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "^\s*$" || req.url != "/token") {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if(req.url == "token" && req.http.cookie ~ "^.*laravel_session=([^;]*);*.*$") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie,"^.*laravel_session=([^;]*);*.*$","\1"));
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.grace = 5m;

    if (beresp.http.X-Reverse-Proxy-TTL) {
        set beresp.ttl = std.duration(beresp.http.X-Reverse-Proxy-TTL + "s", 0s);
        unset beresp.http.X-Reverse-Proxy-TTL;
    } else {
        set beresp.ttl = 5h;
    }

    if(bereq.url == "/token") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }
}
```

This VCL code will allow  the `Set-Cookie` header the be processed. This means that the browser will receive the `laravel_session` cookie, but Varnish will only  use it when receiving the `/token` endpoint during an ESI call.

The `/token` endpoint will be cached, but `vcl_hash` extends the hash key with the session ID for that endpoint.

I'm not a big fan of the `X-Reverse-Proxy-TTL` header logic and `set beresp.ttl = 5h` fallback: the HTTP caching conventions have the `Cache-Control` header for this, so there is no need to re-invent the wheel.

If you use the proper `Cache-Control` headers in your Laravel application, the following `backend_response` logic will do:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.grace = 5m;

    if(bereq.url == "/token") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Indeed I was not using varnish properly and the cookie was never set so no chance that it would match on a post request.

Comment: I will take time to analyse your answer in deep but meanwhile thank you for the time you took to answer ! I am new to varnish and clearly I had not (and still doesn't have) all the principes in mind